# Is there a truly universal wildcard in Grep?

Tags: regex, bbedit

Really basic question here. So I'm told that a dot . matches any character EXCEPT a line break. I'm looking for something that matches any character, including line breaks.

All I want to do is to capture all the text in a website page between two specific strings, stripping the header and the footer. Something like HEADER TEXT(.+)FOOTER TEXT and then extract what's in the parentheses, but I can't find a way to include all text AND line breaks between header and footer, does this make sense? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I need to match several characters, including line breaks, I do:

```
[\s\S]*?
```

Note I'm using a non-greedy pattern

Comment: Thanks guys! What a friendly, useful site. I forgot to mention that I was using grep search in BBEdit, this works wonderfully. You all rock!

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with Perl:

```
$ perl -ne 'print if /HEADER TEXT/ .. /FOOTER TEXT/' file.html
```

To print only the text between the delimiters, use

```
$ perl -000 -lne 'print $1 while /HEADER TEXT(.+?)FOOTER TEXT/sg' file.html
```

The `/s` switch makes the regular expression matcher treat the entire string as a **s**ingle line, which means dot matches newlines, and `/g` means match as many times as possible.

The examples above assume you're cranking on HTML files on the local disk. If you need to fetch them first, use `get` from [`LWP::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-5.834/lib/LWP/Simple.pm):

```
$ perl -MLWP::Simple -le '$_ = get "http://stackoverflow.com";
                          print $1 while m!<head>(.+?)</head>!sg'
```

Please note that parsing HTML with regular expressions as above **does not work in the general case!** If you're working on a quick-and-dirty scanner, fine, but for an application that needs to be more robust, use a real parser.

Answer (score 3):

By definition, `grep` looks for lines which match; it reads a line, sees whether it matches, and prints the line.

One possible way to do what you want is with `sed`:

```
sed -n '/HEADER TEXT/,/FOOTER TEXT/p' "$@"
```

This prints from the first line that matches 'HEADER TEXT' to the first line that matches 'FOOTER TEXT', and then iterates; the '-n' stops the default 'print each line' operation.  This won't work well if the header and footer text appear on the same line.

To do what you want, I'd probably use `perl` (but you could use Python if you prefer).  I'd consider slurping the whole file, and then use a suitably qualified regex to find the matching portions of the file.  However, the Perl one-liner given by '@gbacon' is an almost exact transliteration into Perl of the 'sed' script above and is neater than slurping.

Answer (score 2):

The man page of `grep` says:

> grep, egrep, fgrep, rgrep - print lines matching a pattern

`grep` is not made for matching more than a single line. You should try to solve this task with `perl` or `awk`.

Answer (score 2):

As this is tagged with 'bbedit' and BBedit supports Perl-Style Pattern Modifiers you can allow the dot to match linebreaks with the switch (?s)

(?s).

will match ANY character. And yes,
(?s).+
will match the whole text.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed elsewhere, grep will work for single line stuff.

For multiple-lines (in ruby with Regexp::MULTILINE, or in python, awk, sed, whatever), "\s" should also capture line breaks, so

```
HEADER TEXT(.*\s*)FOOTER TEXT
```

might work ...

Comment: You'd have to be reading the file in a mode that scans multiple lines into memory for that to work.

Comment: Thanks, I added how you would do that in Ruby. IIRC, that's /g in perlish, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

here's one way to do it with gawk, if you have it

```
awk -vRS="FOOTER" '/HEADER/{gsub(/.*HEADER/,"");print}' file
```